# How to Access iCloud container of another application (App developed using another developer profile and icloud container created in that profile)?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

I have an ios app and its using iCloudcontainer to keep the some data of users like "expiry date" of the user. I  am going to create the copy of the  app with different
developer account. I am going to migrate the users from the first app to the second app and it is important to get the  Expiry date stored in the icloud container . Can I access the icloud "expiry date" of the first application from the second application.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to migrate that information externally to iCloud (regardless of how you store it in the new version). This will probably have to happen via some purpose-built administrative tool/process.

Shared containers are only accessible via apps from the same developer

> Multiple apps and users have access to iCloud, but data is segregated and encapsulated in partitions called containers. The containers belonging to your apps cannot be accessed by apps from another developer. (from "About Containers and Databases", https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html)

Apps that use iCloud are not eligible for iTunes Connect transfer per "Criteria for Transferring an App" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

> No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.